# How to use Scapy to determine Wireless Encryption Type?

Tags: python, security, wifi, scapy

I am doing a Security Research on Wireless networks which involves coding a small tool that scans for Wifi Access points in the vicinity. Based on the Encryption type found it goes on with some other security tests.

So far I have python code that uses Scapy to enumerate different access points and whether they have Encryption Enabled (Enc= Y or Enc=N). The code for this is:

```
def sniffAP(p):
    if ( (p.haslayer(Dot11Beacon) or p.haslayer(Dot11ProbeResp))
                 and not aps.has_key(p[Dot11].addr3)):
        ssid       = p[Dot11Elt].info
        bssid      = p[Dot11].addr3
        channel    = int( ord(p[Dot11Elt:3].info))
        capability = p.sprintf("{Dot11Beacon:%Dot11Beacon.cap%}\
                {Dot11ProbeResp:%Dot11ProbeResp.cap%}")

        # Check for encrypted networks
        if re.search("privacy", capability): enc = 'Y'
        else: enc  = 'N'
```

What I want is the ability to distinguish between different Encryption Type (WEP, WPA, WPA2, WPS) using python and scapy. Any ideas?

Comment: tried EAPeak? http://code.google.com/p/eapeak/source/browse/

Comment: EAPeak looks good but as I am writing my own code, I want to know how can I leverage scapy to determine the Encryption Type at packet level. I want to add to my own code, not use a whole other tool

Answer (score 8):

Based on airodump-ng code (aicrack-ng suite), the information you're looking for is inside specific `Dot11Elt` layers. By the way in your code, you get SSID and channel by guessing that they are located in the first and third `Dot11Elt` layers, which seems to be the case, but I don't think it's mandatory.

This code should do the work:

```
def insert_ap(pkt):
    ## Done in the lfilter param
    # if Dot11Beacon not in pkt and Dot11ProbeResp not in pkt:
    #     return
    bssid = pkt[Dot11].addr3
    if bssid in aps:
        return
    p = pkt[Dot11Elt]
    cap = pkt.sprintf("{Dot11Beacon:%Dot11Beacon.cap%}"
                      "{Dot11ProbeResp:%Dot11ProbeResp.cap%}").split('+')
    ssid, channel = None, None
    crypto = set()
    while isinstance(p, Dot11Elt):
        if p.ID == 0:
            ssid = p.info
        elif p.ID == 3:
            channel = ord(p.info)
        elif p.ID == 48:
            crypto.add("WPA2")
        elif p.ID == 221 and p.info.startswith('\x00P\xf2\x01\x01\x00'):
            crypto.add("WPA")
        p = p.payload
    if not crypto:
        if 'privacy' in cap:
            crypto.add("WEP")
        else:
            crypto.add("OPN")
    print "NEW AP: %r [%s], channed %d, %s" % (ssid, bssid, channel,
                                               ' / '.join(crypto))
    aps[bssid] = (ssid, channel, crypto)

aps = {}
sniff(iface='mon0', prn=insert_ap, store=False,
      lfilter=lambda p: (Dot11Beacon in p or Dot11ProbeResp in p))
```

**Update:** this code is now obsolete. An updated version of this code has been [integrated to Scapy](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/1741).