# Sniff open wifi networks using Scapy in Python

Tags: wifi, scapy

I need to sniff Open WiFi networks in Scapy using Python. I don't want to sniff encrypted ones.I've searched and cannot find an appropriate approach or documentation. Here's the Python code:

`z=deque()`

`def ReadPkts(x):`

```
if x.haslayer(Dot11Beacon):

    if x.type==0 and x.subtype==8:  # 0 is management, 8 is Beacon frame
        if x.addr2 not in z:     # ssid
            if x.info not in z:  # bssid
                z.extend((x.info,x.addr2))
```

What i need is a line of code that will detect such networks.
Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to filter out the encrypted networks from the info in the beacon frame?

Comment: Yes. I see that one can detect whether the privacy bit is on, on the capability info in the beacon frame but how do i translate that to a code in Python. or any solution is welcome.

Comment: Anyone out there?

Comment: Sorry, been crushed at work.  Here are some links that might help you.  You can probably use the code to filter your beacon frames. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613091/how-to-use-scapy-to-determine-wireless-encryption-type  https://www.4armed.com/blog/forging-wifi-beacon-frames-using-scapy/